# How to mention # symbol in apache proxy pass?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

I have apache server configured on ubuntu server.

I wanted to know how can I mention # symbol in my proxy pass address like I just wanted to add proxy pass lines like this:

ProxyPass / http://local_server_ip:8080/context_path/#/login

ProxyPassReverse / http://local_server_ip:8080/context_path/#/login

This setup id not working. 
If I remove # symbol it will work and will go to different page.
So is there anyway to add # symbol in proxypass.

Any suggestion please.....

Comment: You don't. The fragment is never passed to the server. It is client side only.

Comment: To clarify further, the processing of the fragment identifier is done on the client side, in JavaScript. In this case, the fragment identifier shows the login dialog. Only way for you to accomplish that is to modify your application code.